# Discord.py SSLCertVerificationError

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have been working on a bot and last night it was working just fine operating as needed but this morning when I opened the bot in my terminal I got this following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Documents/Bots/DS BOT/bot.py", line 58, in <module>
    bot.run(token, bot=False)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection  
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection   
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection     
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)')]
```

My token is up to date, I have the latest versions of both Discord.py and python

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using Windows,

1. Open Internet Explorer preferably as Administrator
2. Open discord.com
3. On address bar, click on the lock icon
4. Click on Install Certificates and install the certificate

Probably you are facing the problem because they were using Sectigo Certificate which expired on 30th May 2020.