# Discord.py after the run shows SSLCertVerificationError. Mismatch of Git openssl lib and conda openssl versions. Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, git, openssl, windows-10, conda

I have got a similiar issue as in this question (certificate verify failed), I was trying to run a python bot for discord:
[Discord.py SSLCertVerificationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107572/discord-py-sslcertverificationerror)

My issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ska19/BlackJack/Coding_Projects/DiscordBots/.vscode/Anekdotemain.py", line 15, in <module>
    bot.run(settings['token'])
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 291, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 483, in _request
    timeout=real_timeout
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 859, in _create_connection
    req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 986, in _create_direct_connection
    req=req, client_error=client_error)
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 939, in _wrap_create_connection
    req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1076)')]
```

I have tried some solutions to the problem:

1. Regenerated bot token
2. Made clock and data accurate to my region
3. Updated conda environment
4. Upgraded certificates in conda (conda install --upgrade certifi)
5. Updated git

None of that has helped, the same issue raises :(

Also I have seen a solution such as go directly to python and run:

```
install Certificate.command
```

But I didn't get how to run the command (sry exhausted).

Or manually install the certificate, but I'm a bit worrying about possible crashes with this method.

After being super confused, I have decided to check the openssl version in git and in conda and have found they are different:

1. Git:

```
$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
built on: Tue Sep 22 14:26:00 2020 UTC
platform: mingw64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(long) idea(int) blowfish(ptr)
compiler: gcc -m64 -Wall -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_MT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -DOPENSSLBIN="\"/mingw64/bin\""
OPENSSLDIR: "/mingw64/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/mingw64/lib/engines-1_1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

2. Conda prompt:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
built on: Fri Sep 27 14:07:54 2019 UTC
platform: VC-WIN64A
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(long) idea(int) blowfish(ptr)
compiler: cl /Zi /Fdossl_static.pdb /Gs0 /GF /Gy /MD /W3 /wd4090 /nologo /O2 -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "C:\ci\openssl_1569593028961\_h_env\Library"
ENGINESDIR: "C:\ci\openssl_1569593028961\_h_env\Library\lib\engines-1_1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

Probably the solution of my problem is to update openssl dir in conda environment or set up  git openssl dir as default
But after clashing with the initial issue for a couple of hours my mind is surrending:(

In case, my code (nothing important):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= settings['prefix'])


@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f'Hello, {author.mention}!')


bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Config file:

```
settings = {
    'token': token,
    'bot': 'AnekdoteBot',
    'id': id,
    'prefix': '!'
}
```

Could anyone help me to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, As I have said, you could install SSL certificates manually.
Check this: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159 - for windows

Found it here [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108) Discord/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411362/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-i)

I have downloaded PEM certifications here: https://crt.sh/?id=1
then installed them on my local computer and it has helped!