# Discord Bot Issues

Tags: python, discord

I am extremely new to doing this. I tried making a simple Discord bot off of YouTube and it wasn't recognizing that had the pip install discord installed. When I input import discord on my script it said that there was a module error.

So then I tried recreating the bot under a new token and new script in a new virtual environment and now I am getting this error:

```
/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/bin/python /Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1089, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1119, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 534, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 974, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonProject/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Users/psudo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/new/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no idea what to do in this situation.

Comment: This does not look like an issue with your code -- this appears to be a networking issue connecting to Discord. Try using a different network and disable any VPN you may have.

Comment: Not running any VPN currently and my network is fine.. maybe I will try the other script I was using and show that

Could it be related to me building 2 bots and not using the first one? Maybe I will try to delete that

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159 (or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107572/discord-py-sslcertverificationerror))

Comment: Well they suggest to do this:

Go to start, type internet explorer. Run as admin.
Go do https://discord.com click on the padlock icon.
Click view certificates
Click install certificates, choose either user or local machine.
Click Place all certificates in the following store
Choose Trusted Root Certification Authorities
Enjoy.

And I dont know if that is wise to do

Not to mention im on mac

Comment: My certificate is valid on the website.. So no that doesn't answer it unfortunately

Comment: For anyone having this issue I was able to resolve it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108183/discord-py-bot-dont-have-certificate

Answer (score 2):

Your code is probably fine. Looking at the error logs it seems your code cannot connect to discord.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).